# NAnt on Windows 7 64 bit - Error setWinVer.6.1

Tags: .net, windows-7, 64-bit, nant

I'm getting some strange errors with NAnt on my 64-bit Win 7 Box.

Targeting a .NET 2.0 application. I have VS 2005 and VS 2010 installed.

This build file works perfect on Xp 32 bit.

When I run it I get:

```
C:\Apps\BLAH\nant.exe -buildfile:BC_STUFF.build BuildAndInstall "-D:SkipSandCastle=true"       
NAnt 0.85 (Build 0.85.2478.0; release; 14/10/2006)
Copyright (C) 2001-2006 Gerry Shaw
http://nant.sourceforge.net

Buildfile: file:///C:/Apps/BLAH/BC_STUFF.build
Target framework: Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0
Target(s) specified: BuildAndInstall 

  [sysinfo] Setting system information properties under sys.*
  [sysinfo] Property could not be created for environment variable 'CommonProgramFiles(x86)' : Property name 'sys.env.CommonProgramFiles(x86)' is invalid.
  [sysinfo] Property could not be created for environment variable 'ProgramFiles(x86)' : Property name 'sys.env.ProgramFiles(x86)' is invalid.
   [script] Scanning assembly "fdii67ui" for extensions.
   [script] Scanning assembly "qv6p_-ys" for extensions.
   [script] Scanning assembly "abosgmew" for extensions.

winVer:


BUILD FAILED - 0 non-fatal error(s), 2 warning(s)

Target 'setWinVer.6.1' does not exist in this project.

Total time: 0.7 seconds.
```

Any thoughts on how to rectify this?

---

Update

I right clicked NAnt.exe and changed it to run in Compatibility mode (Win XP Sp3) and it works, however now it's having a hard time reading from the registry - which is odd). Not the best way, but it seems to have some effect, will keep this updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that Seeing the NAnt.exe properties to run the program as Window XP SP3 compatible was the only way to get this done without upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

Look at what your `winVer` target is doing. It looks like it is forming a target name based on the Windows version and calling that target. In this case, it is `setWinVer.6.1` and that target does not exist in your project.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply manojlds. I've searched every build file we have, and I have not found any winVer. I've also done a text search in our projects directory and not found any winVer. It seems this is a Nant thing.

Answer (score 1):

Some general advice: You are running version 0.85 of NAnt which is more than five years old. I wouldn't expect this version to work without any hassle in a modern environment like Win 7 64 bit. You should definitely consider to switch to version 0.91 and I wouldn't be a bit surprised if that already solves your problem.

Comment: We're planning to upgrade once we remove bizTalk 2006, seeing we're going to need to re-write the build scripts at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I managed to get it working by adding the line  in the project build file (.nant) as below

```
<project name="">
<property name="" value="" />
<target name="setWinVer.6.1"></target>
```